# Freezing the time and date of an array of VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is there a way to freeze the time and date of a VM, so that it is not synchronized with the guest BIOS and/or the internet? I have seen some solutions which talk about killing services inside the VM, but I wish to avoid this as it changes the "clean state" of the VM (used for testing purposes).

To clarify: I don't want to set the time offset for a VM, I want to set the exact time that will be passed to the OS at boot time.

From there, is there a way to do this across a large number of VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving the issue with a python script.

To use it, you edit the `VM_NAMES` list to contain the names of the VMs as they appear in VirtualBox, then set the RESET_TIME_VALUE according to the date and time you wish to send the VMs.

If you have installed VirtualBox in a non-default location, edit the `VIRTUAL_BOX_MANAGE_PATH` variable as well.

To run, call the `main` method.

```
import datetime
import subprocess

VIRTUAL_BOX_MANAGE_PATH         = r"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe"

SET_EXTRA_DATA_COMMAND          = r"setextradata"
GET_HOST_TIME_DISABLE_COMMAND   = "\"VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled\" \"1\""

MODIFY_VM_COMMAND               = r"modifyvm"
BIOS_SYSTEM_TIME_OFFSET         = r"--biossystemtimeoffset"

# Edit this list to add more Virtual Machines
VM_NAMES                        = ("xxx",
                                   "yyy",
                                   "zzz") 

RESET_TIME_VALUE                = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 7, 13, 0, 0, 0)                                

def main():
    for vm in VM_NAMES:
        reset_time(vm)
        disable_time_sync(vm)

def reset_time(vm_name):
    """
        Resets the VM to the clean install time
    """

    args = get_subprocess_args_set_bios_time(vm_name, RESET_TIME_VALUE)
    print("Resetting time on VM [" + vm_name + "] to " + str(RESET_TIME_VALUE) + " ...")

    subprocess.call(args)
    print("\tDone.")    

def disable_time_sync(vm_name):
    """
        Disables the time synchronization of a VM with the BIOS
    """

    args = [
                VIRTUAL_BOX_MANAGE_PATH,
                SET_EXTRA_DATA_COMMAND,
                vm_name,
                GET_HOST_TIME_DISABLE_COMMAND
           ]

    print("Disabling time synchronization on VM [" + vm_name + "] ...")

    subprocess.call(args)
    print("\tDone.")

def get_subprocess_args_set_bios_time(vm_name, datetime_to_set):
    """
        Returns a list containing the arguments to pass to the subprocess method
        to start the Virtual Box Manage program and set the BIOS time to the supplied value
    """

    return [
            VIRTUAL_BOX_MANAGE_PATH, 
            MODIFY_VM_COMMAND, 
            vm_name, 
            BIOS_SYSTEM_TIME_OFFSET, 
            str(get_msec_time_difference(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime_to_set))
           ]

def get_msec_time_difference(reference_point, check_point):
    """
        Computes the offset in msec from the reference point to the check point
    """

    return int(round( (check_point - reference_point).total_seconds() * 1000 ))
```

Answer (score -1):

*" To run, call the main method."*

..or just add at the end of the file

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```